# gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘--interpreter=mi’ in Visual Studio Code

Tags: gcc

I just installed Visual Studio Code in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS based ElementaryOS 5.1 Hera, and set up the environment for C/C++. Launch.json and tasks.json look all fine but on debugging, the following errors are triggered:

```
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘--interpreter=mi’ 
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘--tty=/dev/pts/0’
gcc: fatal error: no input files compilation terminated.
```

launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gcc - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "console": "externalTerminal",
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc build active file",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc"
        }
    ]
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Maybe don't try to launch gcc as your debugger? Try gdb instead, it should work.

Comment: I guess I only have gcc installed, when I set it to gdb, miDebuggerPath becomes invalid.

Comment: So you need to install gdb